# This c code that demonstrates pass by values and pass by references in C doesn't work right

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void passbyvalue(int number);
void passbyreference(int* pNumber);

void passbyreference1(int** pNumber);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int number = 5;
    int* pNumber = &number;

    printf("pNumber in main is %p\n", pNumber);
    printf("*pNumber in main is %d\n", *pNumber);


    printf("number in main is %d\n", number);
    passbyvalue(number);
    printf("number in main is %d\n", number);

    passbyreference(&number);
    printf("number in main is %d\n", number);

    printf("*pNumber in main is %d\n", *pNumber);
    passbyreference1(&pNumber);
    printf("number in main is %d\n", *pNumber);

    // we should free the memory allocated in passbyreference1 once we are done
    // but we have to be careful
    printf("pNumber in main is now %p\n", pNumber);
    printf("freeing pNumber\n");
    free(pNumber);
    pNumber = NULL;
    printf("pNumber in main is now %p\n", pNumber);

    return 0;
}

void passbyvalue(int number)
{
    printf("number in passbyvalue is %d\n", number);
    number = 99;
    printf("number in passbyvalue is %d\n", number);
}

void passbyreference(int* pNumber)
{
    printf("number in passbyreference is %d\n", *pNumber);
    *pNumber = 99;
    printf("number in passbyreference is %d\n", *pNumber);

}

void passbyreference1(int** pNumber)
{
    printf("passbyreference1 can modify the pointer \n");
    // should check for NULL - also this creates a memory leak unless we call free
    int* pN = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("pN in passbyreference1 is %p\n", pN);

    *pN = 234;
    printf("*pN in passbyreference1 is %d\n", *pN);
    
    // this sets the pointer to the new int we created on the heap
    *pNumber = pN;
}
```

I'm trying to understand pointers to a pointer. This code is supposed to demonstrate pass by values and pass by reference. Everything seems to run correctly and I understand everything until I get to the passbyreference1 function. I run the code and I am getting a memory access violation error when the debugger tries to run the line *pN=234.

Tried checking malloc if it is NULL and that wasn't it. Also tried casting malloc to an int* and that didn't work.

Comment: What if you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Works for me after I added `#include <stdlib.h>` to silence the warning about implicit declaration of `free`.  https://godbolt.org/z/hcePxbEGP I also removed the paramters to `main` to avoid the unused variable warnings.

Comment: OMG I feel so dumb. I've been at this for last 4 hours. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: moral of the story: treat compiler warnings as errors unless you really know better

Comment: @cougarhound, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: In c arguments are passed by value.  If you need to change what a pointer points to you need to pass the address of the pointer `int **p`.

Comment: Prefer `main()` at the bottom.  For small examples it means you can get away with not having to write prototypes.  Prefer `int *p` to `int* p`, otherwise you will be confused with `int* p, p2` as `p2` is an `int` not a `int *`.

Comment: @AllanWind The correct way to write C code is to never write crap code such as `int* p, p2`. After which your argument of where to place the * becomes irrelevant. The similarly crappy counter-example would be: https://godbolt.org/z/PrbsEE5an. The solution in either example is simply to not write code containing things widely recognized as bad practices, such as multiple declarations on a single line or hiding pointers behind typedef.

Comment: @Lundin Not sure why you react so strongly ("crap code").  It's fairly common to have multiple definitions in `for()` loops.  Otherwise agree to avoid multiple declarations but see it all the time here.  My point remains that putting the '*' next to the type instead of variable goes against the grain of the c language.

Comment: @AllanWind I've been trying to understand pointers to pointers for a while now and everytime I think I understand it, I get even more confused. I end up just trying different permutations of int **p  int *p  &p p to get things to work....Also questioning my life decisions. lol.

Comment: @cougarhound In c you use `*` to deference a variable, and `&` to take the address of an object (or function).  When you declare a pointer you also use `*`.  Draw some pictures, and like you did write some programs and inspect what is stored in a variable.  `int *p` is a pointer `p` to an int, so it holds an address of another location that stores an int.  `int **p2`  is a pointer that points to location that holds another pointer like `p`).

Comment: @AllanWind Because the style argument you made is from the 1980s and it's getting real tiresome to beat that supposedly dead horse.